# Why for bandpass signals complex envelope and pre-envelope signal representations are used in digital communications/analog communications (FM)?

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, demodulation, analytic-signal

When we need to analyse band pass signals we use complex envelope and preenvelope representations, wherein a signal is given an equivalent **low pass representation.**

My issue is why it is done, though I agree that using a preenvelope or complex envelope remove the carrier amplitude and shift the signal around zero frequency, which eases analyses. But is this the only reason.

I have even searched literature but was not able to get a proper answer. Can somebody help me on this.
I will grateful for a detailed mathematical answer for this question.